# Pytorch custom dataset: ValueError: some of the strides of a given numpy array are negative

Tags: python, pytorch

I wrote a custom pytorch dataset, but ran into an error thhat seems quite unintelligible.

My custom dataset,

```py
class data_from_xlsx(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, xlsx_fp, path_col, class_cols_list):
        self.xlsx_file = pd.read_excel(xlsx_fp)
        self.path_col = path_col
        self.class_cols_list = class_cols_list

    def __len__(self):
        return get_xlsx_length(self.xlsx_file)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        file_path = cols_from_xlsx(self.xlsx_file, index, 1, self.path_col) 
        feature = load_nii_file(file_path) # get 3D volume (x, y, z) 
        feature = np.expand_dims(feature, axis=0) # add channel (c, x, y, z)
        label = cols_from_xlsx(self.xlsx_file, index, 1, self.class_cols_list) # get label
        return feature, label.astype(np.bool)


def main():
dataset = data_from_xlsx("train.xlsx", "file_path", ["pos", "neg"], transformations, aug=True)
    data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=4, shuffle=True)

    for (f, l) in data_loader:
        print("f shape", f.shape)
        print("l shape", l.shape)
```

An error is reported when I ran `main()`,

```
 File "d:\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 346, in __next__
    data = self.dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "d:\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 47, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "d:\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 80, in default_collate
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
  File "d:\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 80, in <listcomp>
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
  File "d:\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 65, in default_collate
    return default_collate([torch.as_tensor(b) for b in batch])
  File "d:\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 65, in <listcomp>
    return default_collate([torch.as_tensor(b) for b in batch])
ValueError: some of the strides of a given numpy array are negative. This is currently not supported, but will be added in future release
```

The reported error does't make sense to me, so I googled it. At first I thought I didn't change the `feature` from `numpy.array` to tensor, so I tried `feature = torch.from_array(feature.copy())` and also tried `transforms.TOTensor()` but both attempts failed.

Comment: To make your life easier you might consider returning torch.tensors or lists of numbers (not numpy arrays) from your dataset. The [default collate function](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/354ecc42bc0affdf83d59609bb340bafc68ba0d4/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py#L43) tries to handle numpy arrays but is apparently failing. The collate function takes a list of multiple outputs from the dataset and converts them into batched torch tensors. An alternative would also be to write your own collate function and give it to the DataLoader (eg `DataLoader(..., collate_fn=my_collate_fn)`)

Comment: this issue has been resolved  as far as I can recall. However, you can return this, `torch.from_numpy(feature.copy())`

Comment: also, I dont think Dataloader supports Numpy bool type, you might need to convert  `label` to tensor as well, `torch.tensor(label.astype(np.bool))`

Comment: @UsmanAli Wow that works perfect! thanks! But I am still so confused about why I should do this. As far as I know, I need to convert the numpy array to torch tensor before I put that into a network. So I also tried to return sth like `torch.FloatTensor(feature)`, and `torch.BoolTensor(label)` but it just didn't work.

Comment: @UsmanAli So I am just being unconfident on when and how should I do this torch tensor conversion.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the advice from @jodag and @UsmanAli, I sovled this by return `torch.from_numpy(feature.copy())` and `torch.tensor(label.astype(np.bool))`
So the whole thing should be,

```py
class data_from_xlsx(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, xlsx_fp, path_col, class_cols_list):
        self.xlsx_file = pd.read_excel(xlsx_fp)
        self.path_col = path_col
        self.class_cols_list = class_cols_list

    def __len__(self):
        return get_xlsx_length(self.xlsx_file)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        file_path = cols_from_xlsx(self.xlsx_file, index, 1, self.path_col) 
        feature = load_nii_file(file_path) # get 3D volume (x, y, z) 
        feature = np.expand_dims(feature, axis=0) # add channel (c, x, y, z)
        label = cols_from_xlsx(self.xlsx_file, index, 1, self.class_cols_list) # get label
        return torch.from_numpy(feature.copy()), torch.tensor(label.astype(np.bool))
```

Comment: Awesome! I had the same issue and wasted almost a day until I found this solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you may need [`numpy.ascontiguousarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html) to return a contiguous array (ndim >= 1) in memory (C order). And then, you can use `torch.from_numpy()`.

Click [this link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/getting-the-some-of-the-strides-of-a-numpy-error-are-negative-on-using-facebook-infersent-model/31837/2?u=goingmyway) for more information.

Good luck.